# jQuery selector behaves differently in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an element that looks like this:

[image]

I use the following selector to point to the **`a`(anchor)** element

> $('.navigation-tabs .profile a')

This selector returns the following in `Chrome`:
[image: Using the selector in Chrome]

Returns the following in `IE`(all versions):

[image: Using the selector in IE11]

What does the result in `IE` mean?

If the objective were to trigger the `click` event on the selector, how do I use the selector result in `IE` to do so?

Comment: What is your issue? I don't get it...

Comment: @A.Wolff `$('.navigation-tabs .profile a').click()` is what I need to trigger in IE. But the selector result is not what it appears in `Chrome`. Read the last statement of my question.

Comment: That's just how object is displayed in console. Both are identical. If you use `$('.navigation-tabs .profile a').click()` on both browsers, it will work the same. So if you have specific issue with this code, ask relevant question. Now just be aware than triggering click on anchor using jQuery doesn't fire native click DOM API method on it. But because i don't know what you are expecting, i'm really not sure it is an issue for you here

Comment: @A.Wolff I thought they meant different things. So I guess my issue is that my `$(selector).click()` does not appear to be working in `IE`. Good to know they meant the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are actually same. Result in chrome *looks* different because IE shows you plain js object, while chrome shows you markup, which is interactive by the way.

In your javascript code, you don't think about it and just use this objects.